# TWAIN API support on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, hardware, api

Does FreeBSD support in any way the TWAIN API? If not, what is the API that could be used to read data from imaging devices (webcams) - preferably in a portable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FOSS scanner/imaging API is [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/). You may need to install Linux compatibility files in order to allow it to access the webcam as a V4L device.

Comment: This is the layer for compatibility with Video4Linux in FreeBSD http://www.freshports.org/multimedia/webcamd/.